# How to analyze the effects of air pollution separately for the warm season and the cool season

Tags: r, time-series, software, seasonality

In the model for main effect, we used the R code:

```
library(dlnm);
library(mgcv);
library(splines);
library(tsModel)

cb.temp   <- crossbasis(data$temp, lag=15, argvar=list(fun="ns",df=3), 
                        arglag=list(fun="strata"));
cb.rh     <- crossbasis(data$rh,   lag=15, argvar=list(fun="ns",df=3), 
                        arglag=list(fun="strata"));
cb.pres   <- crossbasis(data$pres, lag=15, argvar=list(fun="ns",df=3), 
                        arglag=list(fun="strata")).

modelpm10 <- gam(death~runMean(pm10,0:1) + cb.temp + cb.rh + cb.pres + 
                       ns(time,df=7*years) + as.factor(dow), 
                 data=data, family=quasipossion)
```

How to analyze the  effects of air pollution separately for the warm season (April-September) and the cool season (October-March)?